# react-redux get objects from node server

Tags: javascript, subset

I have 21 objects in node and i want that display only 10, how should I do? I use a map to take obj whats next?

code similar as:

```
const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map((todo, index) => (
      <Todo key={index} {...todo} onClick={() => onTodoClick(index)} />
    ))}
  </ul>
)
```

Comment: use splice to get the todos and do the map

Comment: `splice` can mutate the original `todos` list so be cautious.

Answer (score 0):

Use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get a range of items (i.e. all items from index 0 to 9). Relating to your question, it would be

```
const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.slice(0, 10).map((todo, index) => (
      <Todo key={index} {...todo} onClick={() => onTodoClick(index)} />
    ))}
  </ul>
)
```